# MAF application Deployment to iOS simulator in Jdeveloper

Tags: ios, deployment, jdeveloper, xcode7.3, oracle-maf

I am facing problems while deploying the **Mobile Application Framework(MAF)** application in JDeveloper to iOS stimulator.

The logs for deployment are as follows:

```
[11:25:18 AM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[11:25:18 AM] Target platform is  (iOS).
[11:25:18 AM] Beginning deployment of MAF application 'ISSCMobile15.0' to iOS using profile 'iOS1'.
[11:25:18 AM] Checking to detect whether a partial deployment can be done.
[11:25:18 AM] The referenced iOS simulator, "FirstAvailable" is not available.
[11:25:18 AM] Detected: Full deployment is needed
[11:25:18 AM] Capturing initial file state of the MAF application.
[11:25:19 AM] Verifying this is a MAF application...
[11:25:19 AM] Verifying existence of the .adf source directory of the MAF application...
[11:25:19 AM] Verifying Application Controller project exists...
[11:25:19 AM] Verifying application dependencies...
[11:25:19 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[11:25:19 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[11:25:19 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[11:25:19 AM] Failed deployment to iOS simulator. Encountered exception: An error occurred while trying to determine if Xcode is installed..
[11:25:19 AM] An error occurred while trying to determine if Xcode is installed.
[11:25:19 AM] Cannot run program "/Users/msm/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/iOS/maf-helper": error=13, Permission denied
[11:25:19 AM] error=13, Permission denied
```

I tried creating the “New Deployment Profile”  and facing problem in 3rd step as follows:

1. Going to JDeveloper>Application>Deploy>New Deployment Profile…
2. Choosing “MAF for iOS” and click ok.
3. Selecting Minimum iOS version and Simulator and clicking ok.

The problem is that I am not able to get the list of Simulators to select, having Xcode installed. Please see this [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_sNc9AUdAjoY1NnUUZEbmRuRjQ) of what options appears in the Deployment Profile dialog box.

I have installed the MAF extension correctly for JDeveloper and also I am using following softwares:

OS X El Capitan version 10.11.5
Oracle Jdeveloper version 12.2.1.0.0
Xcode version 7.3.1

Please help me deploy the application to iOS simulator.
Thanks.

Comment: Please tell me how to get list of simulators while setting deployment profile.

Comment: normally deployment profiles will come when you add the dependencies.

Comment: Why it isn't able to run program **"/Users/msm/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/iOS/maf-helper": error=13, Permission denied"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey had a problem with Xcode, it seems it wasn't active or so.
So I ran a command "**sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app**" in the terminal and the simulators list got fetched and was able to set deployment profile using iPhone9.3 and the application got deployed.
Thanks [Anand Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4865536/anand-raj) for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please add dependency.
follow the steps. select `ViewController` project properties. then select dependencies. click on "+" button and select "`Build Output`" under `ApplicationController` other option is to check whether the xcode version installed is correct.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Added the dependency but the problem still persists.
The deployment logs are still as it was before.

Comment: did you get the simulator list?

Comment: No, I didn't got them. Please tell me how to get them.

Comment: Do ApplicationController should also have some dependency on ViewController??

Comment: No.. I think there is some problem with the xcode version installed. Could you please try to install the latest version?

Comment: what are the values listed in min os version drop down?

Comment: only 8.0 is listed in min os version drop down.

Comment: select that and check whether list is coming.. in screen shot you are selecting 9.3

Comment: I tried both 8.0( which is coming in dropdown menu) and entered 9.3 manually but the simulator list is not coming for both.

Comment: ok.. then please try the step. go to jdev preference select mobile application framework then ios platform check the option "Automatically added to itunes directory "

Comment: also check whether itunes installed

Comment: Yup.The entry in that is "/Users/msm/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized".

And the iTunes is also installed.

Comment: ok..first go to xcode
create one dummy proj
deploy it there itself
then only all the simulator got installed
once its successfully installed, come back to jdev. u can find the simulators

Comment: But when I click OK to close the Preference dialog box, a "Verification Failed" dialog box is displayed

Comment: verification Failed?